# Angular: Insert new .row on ngFor condition

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Angular so I decided to try their tutorial, but with some small alterations. Basically I have the following array:

```
export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

And the objective is to list them on screen using *ngFor, so I looked up for some ways to do it and this was the most logical thing for me to do, but it's not working.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-secondary padding-sm margin-sm rounded">
    <div class="row">

        <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let index = index">

            <div class="col-lg-4 bg-lightblue rounded">

                <p class="text-secondary lead">
                    <span  class="text-info text-uppercase lead font-weight-bold">
                        {{ hero.name}}
                    </span> 

                    Details
                </p>

                <p>
                    <span class="font-weight-bold text-success">
                        ID: 
                    </span>

                    {{ hero.id }}
                </p>

                <p>
                    <span class="font-weight-bold text-success">
                        Name: 
                    </span>

                    {{ hero.name }}
                </p>

                <label class="font-weight-bold">Change name: 
                    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" class="input-md" type="text" placeholder="name">
                </label>

            </div>

            {{ (index + 1) % 3 }}

            <div class="row" *ngIf="(index + 1) % 3 == 0"></div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm attempting to do is to start cycling through the list and when it reaches 3 columns, it adds a row by checking if *(index + 1) % 3* equals 0 and continues adding columns on the next row.
Right now it's not adding the row when the condition in ngIf is true. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried an `*ngIf="{{((index + 1) % 3) == 0}}"` on the row div?
Else `*ngIf="{{((index + 1) % 3) != 0}}"` on a column div?

Comment: I tried both and adding the {{}} around the condition doesn't work, I think it's because the variable index is created in ngFor, hence not accessible like that. Regarding the 2nd suggestion, what it does is not adding the columns when the condition is true. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If the intent is just to add some margin space between groupings it's the type of thing I'd suggest using CSS for with say `:nth-child(3n)` selector instead of adding a repeated eval with additional DOM elements added to do it. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare `heroes` and update it as you want to display in HTML i.e. 3 columns in a row

```
heroes = [];
HEROES.forEach((hero, index) => {
    if(index % 3 == 0) {
        let row = [];
        row.push(hero);
        this.heroes.push(row);
    } else {
        this.heroes[this.heroes.length - 1].push(hero);
    }
});
```

it will generate `heroes` as:

```
[ 
  [ { "id": 11, "name": "Mr. Nice" }, { "id": 12, "name": "Narco" }, { "id": 13, "name": "Bombasto" } ], 
  [ { "id": 14, "name": "Celeritas" }, { "id": 15, "name": "Magneta" }, { "id": 16, "name": "RubberMan" } ], 
  [ { "id": 17, "name": "Dynama" }, { "id": 18, "name": "Dr IQ" }, { "id": 19, "name": "Magma" } ], [ { "id": 20, "name": "Tornado" } ] 
]
```

then you can update HTML as you want.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let rowData of heroes">
    <div class="col-lg-4 bg-lightblue rounded" *ngFor="let hero of rowData">
        <p class="text-secondary lead">
            <span  class="text-info text-uppercase lead font-weight-bold">{{ hero.name}}</span> Details
        </p>
        <p>
            <span class="font-weight-bold text-success">ID: </span>{{ hero.id }}
        </p>
        <p>
            <span class="font-weight-bold text-success">Name: </span>{{ hero.name }}
        </p>
        <label class="font-weight-bold">Change name: 
            <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" class="input-md" type="text" placeholder="name">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks interesting and I'm curious to see how it behaves when the row isn't complete. I'll try it once I get home and let you know my results. Thank you.