# How do i add bootstrao col-lg {n} dynamically based on on record length

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Below Is the result that i want

```
1.let suppose i have only one record then it should take "col-lg-12"
2.if i have 2 records then it should be like "col-lg-6" & "col-lg-6"
3.if i have 3 records then it should be like "col-lg-4" & "col-lg-4" & "col-lg-4".
4.if i have four record then it should be like first row of col-lg-4 each and next row will be col-lg-12


How can i do this
```

Comment: typical `*ngFor` combined with `[ngClass]` per containing element. what isnt working ?

Comment: <div  class="col-lg-4"  style="padding-left: 0px !important" *ngFor = 'let data of related_documents'>
                    
</div>  this is my current loop i want col-lg size will be generated by the cont of related document

Comment: You can't control it through HTML only, you have to modify data as well, check similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50673735/264946.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this code check this out

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    records=['data','data2'];
    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){}    
}
```

Your Html File Should be Like This

```
<div *ngFor="let record of records;let i=index" class="col-md-{{12/+records.length}}" >
{{record}}{{i/1}}
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work at least in the case of no records.

Comment: you can add ternary operator to it so it will work perfectly

Comment: It is working upto 3 count but if it is 4 then i want the first row to be col-lg-4 each and next row will be col-lg-12

Comment: Below is the code of my ts file    this.related_documents = data['related_docment']; this.count_related = this.related_documents.length;
    this.forloop = Math.ceil(this.count_related/3);this.forRowLoop = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= this.forloop; i++) {this.forRowLoop.push(i);}
    $scope.Math = window.Math;        And now my html file    <div class="row" *ngFor="let rdata of forRowLoop;let i = index">{{rdata}}<div *ngFor = 'let data of related_documents;let ii = index'> <div class="col-lg-{{12/+count_related}}"   *ngIf="Math.ceil((ii/3)) == rdata"> </div></div></div>

Comment: if you have four record how your html should look can you add the static html structure